# Complex numbers and matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

I've studied that there is an *isomorphism* beetween *complex numbers* and 2x2 *conformal* matrices.

Is it correct to say that complex numbers always represent a transformation, or are they used in other ways?

Comment: In what sense do you mean “are they used in other ways?”. I can tell you for certain that complex numbers are more than just arbitrary numbers used for transformations, and there’s dozen of courses devoted solely to complex numbers, the complex plane, etc

Comment: I was introduced to complex numbers by the isomorphism with 2x2 conformal matrices. So, my initial doubt was : are complex numbers and conformal matrices two mathematical tools that represent the SAME mathematical operations ? (or maybe complex numbers are used in other ways , that , at the moment i'm unware of.

Comment: That’s a loaded question to be honest, but geometrically speaking, _visualizing_ is the best way to get a good first grasp of them. That’s why so many “complex fields of mathematical study” use visual analysis all the time. Understanding their applications in full though would take quite of bit of explanation. They’re used in all sorts of things in math and physics. I’d suggest picking up _Visual Complex Analysis_ by Needham

Comment: Why can be useful watching complex numbers as matrices ?